# login user with one more parameter in the credential and return error for that parameter

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to send an error message to the login page when the user enters the email and password correctly, so that user should wait for the admin confirmation, I wrote bellow code and the problem is when user enter the wrong password it's send fail message again as well, how can I handle this?

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1 ])){
            return redirect()->route('user.home');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('user.login')->with('fail', 'pleas wait till admin confirmation');
        }
```

Comment: You can't determine what part of the credentials 'failed' via this method ... it is just pass or fail (either a user was found by these credentials [including the `status` field] or a user was not found) ... technically you could know if the password didn't match but that is it

Comment: so what should I do? any idea?

Comment: yea you will have to do what `attempt` is doing yourself and retrieve the user by the credentials, validate the credentials, then check if that status field is the correct value and log them in if everything is good, if not return the appropriate error message

Comment: thanks, Let see what can be done

Comment: I would look at `SessionGuard@attempt` and see what it is doing ... there is a `UserProvider` (which your configuration has set to `EloquentUserProvider`, `eloquent` driver, by default)  that you can use to find the user by credentials and validate those credentials ... it will also show you how it goes about doing the login part after that

Comment: I see but there is not any validation for for the credentials

Comment: Are you using any first party authentication package like Breeze? Or you have your own implementation?

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to try using the concept of Laravel's `MustVerifyEmail`.

Say you define a method on User model `isConfirmedByAdmin()`

```php
//User.php

public function isConfirmedByAdmin()
{
    return $this->status === 1;
}
```

Then make a middleware

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class EnsureIsConfirmedByAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $redirectToRoute
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|null
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = 'login')
    {
        if (! $request->user() || ! $request->user()->isConfirmedByAdmin()) {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? abort(403, 'Please wait till you are confirmed by Admin.')
                    : Redirect::guest(URL::route($redirectToRoute))->with('wait', 'Please wait till you are confirmed by Admin.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And apply this middleware to the route as required.

```php
if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
    return redirect()->route('user.home');
}
```

The above will login the user with valid credentials. But then the middleware `EnsureIsConfirmedByAdmin` when applied to the route `user.home` will check if the user has been confirmed by Admin, if not it will redirect to the login page (or any other page like verification notice in case of verify email) and the flash message can be displayed to the user.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work